# Run Excel Macro from Outside Excel Using VBScript From Command Line

Tags: excel, vba, command-line, vbscript

I'm trying to run an Excel macro from outside of the Excel file. I'm currently using a ".vbs" file run from the command line, but it keeps telling me the macro can't be found. Here is the script I'm trying to use

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("test.xls")

objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.Workbooks.Add
objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Test value"

objExcel.Application.Run "Macro.TestMacro()"
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close


objExcel.Application.Quit
WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

And here is the Macro I'm trying to access:

```
Sub TestMacro()
'first set a string which contains the path to the file you want to create.
'this example creates one and stores it in the root directory
MyFile = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\" & "TestResult.txt"
'set and open file for output
fnum = FreeFile()
Open MyFile For Output As fnum
'write project info and then a blank line. Note the comma is required
Write #fnum, "I wrote this"
Write #fnum,
'use Print when you want the string without quotation marks
Print #fnum, "I printed this"
Close #fnum
End Sub
```

I tried the solutions located at [Is it possible to run a macro in Excel from external command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183286/is-it-possible-to-run-a-macro-in-excel-from-external-command) to get this far (and modified of course) but it didn't seem to work. I keep getting the error `Microsoft Office Excel: The macro 'Macro.TestMacro' cannot be found.

EDIT: Excel 2003.

Comment: Did you try removing the "Macro." and/or the parenthesis and just call it like this objExcel.Application.Run "TestMacro" ?

Comment: objExcel.Application.Run "test.xls!Macro.TestMacro"

Comment: Those both don't work either :(

Comment: Oh, one thing that you may need to do is save test.xls as an .xlsm macro enabled Workbook.

Comment: @rar: There are many mistakes in the code. I have 3 questions for you. 1) Does TestMacro() reside in test.xls module? 2) Why are you adding a workbook? 3) Why are you writing to the cell Cells(1, 1)?

Comment: 1) No, but I moved it there and I was able to access it there.
2) It was example code I found, and I forgot to modify that part out before posting it.
3) Again, example code. I've removed it from my final test case.

Comment: @rar: Ok. I have posted the code which I tested and tried but i guess it doesn't matter as you have got your answer :)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Ok, it's actually simple. Assuming that your macro is in a module,not in one of the sheets, you use:

```
  objExcel.Application.Run "test.xls!dog" 
  'notice the format of 'workbook name'!macro
```

For a filename with spaces, encase the filename with quotes.

If you've placed the macro under a sheet, say sheet1, just assume sheet1 owns the function, which it does.

```
    objExcel.Application.Run "'test 2.xls'!sheet1.dog"
```

Notice: You don't need the macro.testfunction notation you've been using.

Comment: I didn't realize it had to be in a Module, I had it in the workbook (I could also have tried the second part if I left it in one of the sheets). Thanks!

Comment: Can the Macro be saved in a different file than the Excel? So I can use it on other Excel file without having to add it to each Excel? Thanks

Comment: This considers calling a single macro from several excel files. Is this what you are wanting?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634345/can-you-refer-to-an-external-macro-with-excel

Answer (score 25):

This code will open the file Test.xls and run the macro `TestMacro` which will in turn write to the text file `TestResult.txt`

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp, xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'~~> Change Path here
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Test.xls", 0, True)
xlApp.Run "TestMacro"
xlBook.Close
xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 5):

Since my related question was removed by a righteous hand after I had killed the whole day searching how to beat the "macro not found or disabled" error, posting here the only syntax that worked for me (application.run didn't, no matter what I tried)

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

' Didn't run this way from the Modules
'objExcel.Application.Run "c:\app\Book1.xlsm!Sub1"
' Didn't run this way either from the Sheet
'objExcel.Application.Run "c:\app\Book1.xlsm!Sheet1.Sub1"
' Nor did it run from a named Sheet
'objExcel.Application.Run "c:\app\Book1.xlsm!Named_Sheet.Sub1"

' Only ran like this (from the Module1)

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("c:\app\Book1.xlsm")
objExcel.Run "Sub1"
```

Excel 2010, Win 7

Comment: Great solution, thanks! You might want to add `objWorkbook.Close` and `objExcel.Application.Quit`, otherwise the Excel process is still running.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to adapt @Siddhart's code to a relative path to run my `open_form` macro, but it didn't seem to work.  Here was my first attempt.  My working solution is below.

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp, xlBook
dim fso
dim curDir
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
curDir = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
set fso = nothing

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'~~> Change Path here
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(curDir & "Excels\CLIENTES.xlsb", 0, true)
xlApp.Run "open_form"
xlBook.Close
xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Echo "Finished."
```

**EDIT**

I have actually worked it out, just in case someone wants to run a userform "alike" a stand alone application:

Issues I was facing:

1 - I did not want to use the Workbook_Open Event as the excel is locked in read only. 
2 - The batch command is limited that the fact that (to my knowledge) it cannot call the macro.

I first wrote a macro to launch my userform while hiding the application:

```
Sub open_form()
 Application.Visible = False
 frmAddClient.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

I then created a vbs to launch this macro (doing it with a relative path has been tricky):

```
dim fso
dim curDir
dim WinScriptHost
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
curDir = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
set fso = nothing

Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.application")
xlObj.Workbooks.Open curDir & "\Excels\CLIENTES.xlsb"
xlObj.Run "open_form"
```

And I finally did a batch file to execute the VBS...

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
cscript Add_Client.vbs
```

Note that I have also included the "Set back to visible" in my `Userform_QueryClose`:

```
Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Application.Visible = True
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Anyway, thanks for your help, and I hope this will help if someone needs it

Comment: It's great that you eventually found a solution, but you should know that your first version of this answer wasn't an answer, it was a question.  In the future, please post questions as questions, not as answers.  You might want to [go through the site introduction again](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 3):

I tried the above methods but I got the "macro cannot be found" error.
This is final code that worked!

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp, xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True

  ' Import Add-Ins
xlApp.Workbooks.Open "C:\<pathOfXlaFile>\MyMacro.xla"
xlApp.AddIns("MyMacro").Installed = True

'
Open Excel workbook
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("<pathOfXlsFile>\MyExcel.xls", 0, True)

' Run Macro
xlApp.Run "Sheet1.MyMacro"

xlBook.Close
xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

In my case, MyMacro happens to be under Sheet1, thus Sheet1.MyMacro.

Comment: thanks! when is the "Import Add-Ins" section needed?

Answer (score 2):

I generally store my macros in `xlam` add-ins separately from my workbooks so I wanted to open a workbook and then run a macro stored separately.

Since this required a VBS Script, I wanted to make it "portable" so I could use it by passing arguments. Here is the final script, which takes 3 arguments.

- Full Path to Workbook
- Macro Name
- [OPTIONAL] Path to separate workbook with Macro

I tested it like so:

```
"C:\Temp\runmacro.vbs" "C:\Temp\Book1.xlam" "Hello"

"C:\Temp\runmacro.vbs" "C:\Temp\Book1.xlsx" "Hello" "%AppData%\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\Book1.xlam"
```

**runmacro.vbs:**

```
Set args = Wscript.Arguments

ws = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
macro = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)
If wscript.arguments.count > 2 Then
 macrowb= WScript.Arguments.Item(2)
End If

LaunchMacro

Sub LaunchMacro() 
  Dim xl
  Dim xlBook  

  Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
  Set xlBook = xl.Workbooks.Open(ws, 0, True)
  If wscript.arguments.count > 2 Then
   Set macrowb= xl.Workbooks.Open(macrowb, 0, True)
  End If
  'xl.Application.Visible = True ' Show Excel Window
  xl.Application.run macro
  'xl.DisplayAlerts = False  ' suppress prompts and alert messages while a macro is running
  'xlBook.saved = True ' suppresses the Save Changes prompt when you close a workbook
  'xl.activewindow.close
  xl.Quit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run the macro from your personal workbook it might not work as opening an Excel file with a VBScript doesnt automatically open your PERSONAL.XLSB. you will need to do something like this:

```
Dim oFSO
Dim oShell, oExcel, oFile, oSheet
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb2 = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\..\PERSONAL.XLSB") 'Specify foldername here

oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False


For Each oFile In oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Location\").Files
    If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile)) = "xlsx" Then
        With oExcel.Workbooks.Open(oFile, 0, True, , , , True, , , , False, , False)



            oExcel.Run wb2.Name & "!modForm"


            For Each oSheet In .Worksheets



                oSheet.SaveAs "C:\test\" & oFile.Name & "." & oSheet.Name & ".txt", 6


            Next
            .Close False, , False
        End With
    End If



Next
oExcel.Quit
oShell.Popup "Conversion complete", 10
```

So at the beginning of the loop it is opening personals.xlsb and running the macro from there for all the other workbooks. Just thought I should post in here just in case someone runs across this like I did but cant figure out why the macro is still not running.

Answer (score 0):

Hi used this thread to get the solution , then i would like to share what i did just in case someone could use it.

What i wanted was to call  a macro that change some cells and erase some rows, but i needed for more than 1500 excels( approximately spent 3 minuts for each file)

Mainly problem:
-when calling the macro from vbe , i got the same problem, it was imposible to call the macro from PERSONAL.XLSB, when the script oppened the excel didnt execute personal.xlsb and wasnt any option in the macro window

I solved this by keeping open one excel file with the macro loaded(a.xlsm)(before executing the script)

Then i call the macro from the excel oppened by the script

```
    Option Explicit
    Dim xl
    Dim counter

   counter =10



  Do

  counter = counter + 1

  Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
  xl.Application.Workbooks.open "C:\pruebas\macroxavi\IA_030-08-026" & counter & ".xlsx"
  xl.Application.Visible = True
  xl.Application.run "'a.xlsm'!eraserow" 
  Set xl = Nothing


  Loop Until counter = 517

  WScript.Echo "Finished."
  WScript.Quit
```