# How to call a macro script in qtp and to run that macro script in excel

Tags: macros, qtp

I have a created a macro script by recording in excel. Now I need to run this macro script in newly opened excel via QTP (Vb script) . Can anyone suggest me , what call function can be used in qtp to run this macro script in excel?
my macro script is

```
Sub csi()
    ' csi Macro
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+c
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "test test test "
    Range("B1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained [as an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232150/run-excel-macro-from-outside-excel-using-vbscript-from-command-line) it is not very difficult:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.Run "test.xls!csi"
```

or

```
objExcel.Application.Run "test.xls!sheet1.csi"
```

Depending if the macro resides in a `module` or in a `sheet`.

Comment: I think you can just add them as parameters in the `Run` call: `objExcel.Application.Run "test.xls!csi", "Hello World!", 42` as explained for [Visual Basic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153307/en-us).