# Executing VBA out of Shell

Tags: shell, vba, excel, pentaho

I am generating Excel Files with *Pentaho Data Integration* and I want to start a Macro automaticly after creation.
Until now, the Macro is started while opening the file.
But this is not a good way: Some users dont have permissions to execute Macros and each time you open the file Excel is asking if you want to save the changes.

I am wondering if there is a way to execute a VBA Macro in MS Excel out of the Windows Shell.
What I found is this code to open a file:

```
Shell "C:\Programme\Office2k\Office\EXCEL.EXE " & _"C:\...\MyExcelFile.xls"
```

But this is not what I want. I want to start the Macro exactly one time, and before any user opened it.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Would you consider using vbscript ?

Comment: you can't run a macro from a closed file on a closed file. There is a `Workbook_Open()` function you could look into but that's just an alternative (requires opening)

Comment: mehow : That is what I do now. Not a good way. 
@d-stroyer : Thanks, VBScript could be the answer. I found a possible way here [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232150/run-excel-macro-from-outside-excel-using-vbscript-from-command-line)

Comment: I assume the macro does something not related to the data in the spreadsheet correct? If it's doing something with data, why no do that in PDI?

Comment: @Brian.D.Myers The Macro is does some automatic corrections on the data and is marking them in the sheet.In PDI, as far as i know, i can only load data into the Excel File. I can't mark some values and also i can't load excel-functions in some cells in a special case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution with vbscript looks like this (Open, Save, Close without User Interaction):

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\dev\testo.xls")

objExcel.Application.Run "testo.xls!test"
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close 

objExcel.Application.Quit
WScript.Quit
```