# How to execute vba from vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I search [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232150/run-excel-macro-from-outside-excel-using-vbscript-from-command-line) on this site , but they do not have complete info

I have a file `c: ....test.xlsm` it has a subroutine `test ()`

```
sub test () 
msgbox "hello stackoverflow"
end sub
```

---

I want to write a vbscript that would

1) open `c: ....test.xlsm`

2) run `test ()` subroutine

3) close `c: ....test.xlsm`

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is in a module, you would call it like so

```
dim eApp
set eApp = GetObject("C:\wb.xlsm")
eApp.Application.Run "wb.xlsm!test"
set eApp = nothing
```