# Can VBE be invoked/used OUTSIDE of an Office Application?

Tags: ms-office, vbe

This may be a silly question - I haven't found *anything* on Google about this. No new programs populate in the task manager when VBE is opened from an Office Application, and I don't see an executable that looks probable. DLL maybe?

Comment: VBE is embed within each office application and can't be run separately. You can access VBE via Extensibility library or WinApi but it's not as a standalone application nor executable.

Answer (score 0):

Some Office applications provide the Run method for the Application class. For example, see [Run Excel Macro from Outside Excel Using VBScript From Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232150/run-excel-macro-from-outside-excel-using-vbscript-from-command-line).

Yes, you can call VBA macro at runtime.

There are applications that don't provide any specific methods for that, for example, Outlook. In that case you can use the late-binding technology (see Type.InvokeMemeber) - see [Calling Outlook VBA Macro from outside (VB/VBScript/C#)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sachinsancheti/archive/2006/05/16/598951.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke a `CommandBarButton`'s `OnAction` macro as a proxy for `Application.Run`.

For details, see this question [How can I run a macro from a VBE add-in, without Application.Run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954364/how-can-i-run-a-macro-from-a-vbe-add-in-without-application-run)