# access excel sheet cell properties in C

Tags: c, excel, raspberry-pi, cell

I am trying to search a way to access excel sheet properties using C language. What i found on internet they are for C# etc. actually I will be modifying the text properties of an excel sheet in RPi using C language. Plz suggest is there any way.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking specifically about Excel spreadsheets, it is not possible to use C in order to interface directly with Excel. As you mentioned, it is possible to use C#. That's because Microsoft happens to provide an API for that language but doesn't for C.

You could try a XLSX library such as [this one](http://www.libxl.com) (although it is in C++) in order to create spreadsheets.

Comment: Yes, the library will.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably in principle possible to do what you want (Microsoft provides a [C API for Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/bb687829(v=office.14).aspx)) but using it seems fairly involved. A relatively low-tech solution might be to use VBScript as an intermediary. There is a wealth of information on automating Excel with VBScript and it is easy to invoke these scripts from the command line (with e.g. the data you want written to a file passed as a command line argument). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10232150/4996248) question. Furthermore, you can use a system call to invoke this from C (using `system` from `stlib.h`. This is round-about but you can break the problem into 2 steps: writing the VBScript and then figuring out how to invoke it from C.

Comment: Thanks John i would like to try this but will it work for RPi too?

Comment: @Sidk I wouldn't think it would work *directly* in RPi. My answer was mostly about a way to get data from a C program to an Excel document. Presumably the document itself isn't on the RPi and you are using some link to a machine running Windows. Does that link allow you to run system calls? Maybe this contains some helpful ideas: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=67836&p=495685 (that part about XML format sounds promising).

Comment: yeah checked thanks for the link, any idea how can i use this excel XML format in my C code?

Comment: @Sidk This link gives information on Excel XML: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2005/06/27/433152.aspx For writing XML in a specific format you can probably do it yourself, although doubtless you would be reinventing wheels already invented in libraries like: http://www.xmlsoft.org/index.html