# VBScript to call macro not stored within Excel file, but in a XLAM add-in

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I've found a few threads that are similar to what I'm trying to do, but I need to call a macro stored in an XLAM add-in.

I have an XLAM which contains custom add-in functions available to any Excel file.  I am trying to call a macro within that XLAM.  I am using the `Workbooks.Add` rather than opening a specific file.  Below is the code I'm using:

```
Option Explicit

RunMacro

Sub RunMacro()

  Dim xlApp
  Dim xlBook

  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
  xlApp.Run "C:\ATPBGC97\atpbgc2007.xlam\ExportModules"
  xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
  xlBook.Saved = False
  xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close

  Set xlBook = Nothing
  Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I used the thread [Run Excel Macro from Outside Excel Using VBScript From Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232150/run-excel-macro-from-outside-excel-using-vbscript-from-command-line) to get this far.  When I run the script, I get a 'Cannot run the macro' error.  I'm not exactly sure what the syntax should be in my case or if I should just open a dummy file to gain access to the XLAM.

Comment: Assuming the addin is loaded by default, just use `xlApp.Run "ExportModules"`

Comment: @Comintern - yes, the add-in is loaded by default.  I tried that and get the error "Cannot run the macro 'ExportModules'.  The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."

Comment: Try replacing all of the code below the line `Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add` with `xlApp.Visible = True`.  When the Excel instance loads up, check to see if the addin is loaded. If not, you might just need to load it manually.

Comment: @Comintern - yeah, you're right - it doesn't load them when Excel opens this way.  When I open a blank worksheet, it does load the addins.  I guess I'll have to find another way, as loading it manually defeats the purpose of this script.  Thanks

Comment: You might want to try `xlApp.Addins("atpbgc2007").IsLoaded = True` to see if it will load dynamically at runtime. I've had various luck in calling that  via VB though.

Comment: Did u ever resolve this? I'm trying to do the same thing and no luck, works fine if I call `xlsm` and the macro inside that file, but not external `xlam` add-in.

Answer (score 0):

```
xlApp.open "myfile.xlsm"
xlApp.open "myaddin.xlam"
xlApp.run "mymacro"
```

Worked for me. Make sure your macro has a stop to be able to edit it.