# VBA Macro not opened from VBScript through Windows Service

Tags: vba, excel

I have a windows service that calls VBScript. In VBScript, I have a lot of functions and at the end of all execution I call VBA Macro file. Everything is working as expected, expect calling VBA Macro.

Below is the VBScript code to call VBA Macro file

```
sub OpenVBAMacroFile ()
   Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   Set XlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\VBAMacroFile.xlsm")
   xlApp.Run "DataRefresh2"   
   Set xlBook = Nothing
   Set xlApp = Nothing
end sub
```

When I run VBScript manually, VBA Macro file is opening successfully. But, when I run through Windows service, VBAM Macro file is not opening.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: it might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/10232925/7889129

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search, found an answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/ac2549f5-fc1e-494d-9015-70cb31d3aeb2/opening-excel-workbook-fails-when-run-from-scheduled-task-on-windows-server-2008-rw?forum=exceldev)

Solution for the issue is to have directory structure `c:\windows\syswow64\config\systemprofile\desktop`

I do not know how it started working for me. Believe me, this helped for lot of people in the [blog](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/ac2549f5-fc1e-494d-9015-70cb31d3aeb2/opening-excel-workbook-fails-when-run-from-scheduled-task-on-windows-server-2008-rw?forum=exceldev)