# Run Excel Macro automatically every day at specific time without opening workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I've read some of the other questions/responses such as:
[Automatically run macro daily without opening any workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230625/automatically-run-macro-daily-without-opening-any-workbooks/53230949#)
and these are all discussing how to automatically run a macro without opening a workbook at PC start-up.  Is there a way to schedule when the macro will run (without opening an Excel workbook) for a specific time?  Reason being, my work computer often runs continuously for an entire week and only gets shut down & restarted on the weekend.  Therefore, having the macro auto-run upon start-up would do me no good, I need to schedule it to run say every weekday morning at 10am central.  Is that possible and if so, how do I do that?

Comment: Task Scheduler... and there are a lot of resources out there to guide you.

Comment: The question you linked says exactly what to do, just set it to a time instead of on boot.

Answer (score 0):

If you can write VBA, you can learn VBS. It's worth a look to consider as an alternative to using Excel but working with a similar syntax and layout.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/464a3bb3-3bcd-47a0-ab03-f0b8910f2ed1/how-to-run-a-vbs-file-using-task-scheduler?forum=windowsserver2008r2general