# Call Word/Excel Macro from External File

Tags: vba, matlab, excel

The following MATLAB code runs the macro `test` saved as a module in the excel file `test.xlsx`:

```
filename = 'test.xlsx';
Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Open(filename);
Excel.Application.Run("test");
```

Is there a way to run the same macro `test`, when it is saved in an external Basic Macro file, `functions.bas`, or as a text file, or as a string in memory,  without turning the office file into a macro enable document?

```
Function test()
    MsgBox "Hello World"   
End Function
```

Comment: here is a similar question ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183286/is-it-possible-to-run-a-macro-in-excel-from-external-command

Comment: No, not without importing the bas file into Excel.  There's no need for that though: the code doesn't have to be part of a document to be able top operate on that document: you can place the code inside an add-in or just an Excel file, and call it from there.

Comment: @jsotola Note that i am already doing that. The question is about we can take the macro from a 'bas', or a text file, or a string in memory. But as pointed by TimWilliams storing it in a empty 'xls' wouldn be so terrible.